# django-rest-framework-datatables and Django Parler's translation field

Tags: django, datatables, django-rest-framework, django-datatable, django-parler

I've got model with translated fields.

```
class Device(TranslatableModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(name=models.CharField(max_length=100))
```

I made a serializer like:

```
class DeviceSerializer(TranslatableModelSerializer):
    translations = TranslatedFieldsField(shared_model=Device)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('translations',)
```

It gives me nice JSON like it should.

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
          "device": {
               "translations": {
                   "en": {
                       "name": "Sample Device"
                    }
                }
           }              
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to use it with django-rest-framework. In my template I've written script like:

```
$('#devices').DataTable({
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': 'api/devices/?format=datatables',
    'columns': [
        {'data':'device.translations.en'}
```

It refuses to work with me. I am getting django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'en' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.
If I am not appending .en to {'data'} it gives Object.object of course.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in template file.

> Pass name & data field separately to  columns in data-table configuration

please replace `field_name` with your model field name

```
$('#devices').DataTable({
    'ajax': 'api/devices/?format=datatables',
    'columns': [
        {"data": "translations.en.field_name" , "name": "translations.field_name"},
    ]
});
```

for more details refer [django-rest-framework-datatables](https://github.com/izimobil/django-rest-framework-datatables)

& [Django-parler-rest](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler-rest)

> The actual problem is that while making get request to server
> data-table will add name value in column parameter so
>
> instead of writing
>
> "name": "translations.en.field_name"
>
> write down:
>
> "name": "translations.field_name"
>
> remove language code